# Exceção ao acessar web service em aplicação Xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, sql-server, web-service, xamarin-forms

Estou criando uma aplicação com Xamarin com Visual Studio 2017.
Fiz todos os testes no web service e ele acessa o banco de dados e grava tudo perfeitamente na versão do navegador. Agora fiz uma implementação no aplicativo Xamarin e neste caso está ocorrendo uma exceção ao inicializar a base de dados.
O banco de dados já existe e já há dados gravados no banco. Fiz a publicação usando os serviços de informações da internet (iis) no windows 10.
As descrições das exceções estão abaixo.

**Message**

> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: O servidor não pôde
>   processar a solicitação. ---> System.Exception: An exception occurred
>   while initializing the database. See the InnerException for details.
>   em ServiceWebFlipDigital.WSFlipDigital.GravarAgencia(String
>   jsonAgencia) na C:\Users\davinc131\documents\visual studio
>   2017\Projects\WebServiceFlipDigital\ServiceWebFlipDigital\WSFlipDigital.asmx.cs:linha
>   65    --- Fim do rastreamento de pilha de exceções internas ---

**Tracke**

> at
>   FlipDigital.Droid.Implementacoes.Dados.ImplementGravarAgencia.GravarAgencia
>   (System.String jsonAgencia) [0x0001f] in
>   E:\Projetos_Xamarin\FlipDigital\FlipDigital\FlipDigital.Android\Implementacoes\Dados\ImplementGravarAgencia.cs:49
>   at FlipDigital.Portatil.GravarAgenciaManager.GravarAgencia
>   (System.String jsonAgencia) [0x00001] in
>   E:\Projetos_Xamarin\FlipDigital\FlipDigital\FlipDigital\Portatil\GravarAgenciaManager.cs:15
>   at
>   FlipDigital.Views.FlipDigital_CadastroAgencia+d__5.MoveNext
>   () [0x0017d] in
>   E:\Projetos_Xamarin\FlipDigital\FlipDigital\FlipDigital\Views\FlipDigital_CadastroAgencia.xaml.cs:71

O que pode estar ocorrendo e como proceder para resolver o problema?

**NO XAMARIN**

**Interface**

```
public interface IGravarAgencia
{
    void GravarAgencia(string jsonAgencia);

    void ModificarAgencia(string jsonAgencia);

    Agencia ConsultarAgencia(int idAgencia);

    void RemoverAgencia(int idAgencia);

    List<Agencia> ListarAgencias();
}


public void GravarAgencia(string jsonAgencia)
    {
        DependencyService.Get<IGravarAgencia>().GravarAgencia(jsonAgencia);
    }
```

**Essa é a implementação**`

```
public void GravarAgencia(string jsonAgencia)
    {
        try
        {
            wsFlipDigital = new WebServiceFlipDigital.WSFlipDigital();
            wsFlipDigital.GravarAgencia(jsonAgencia);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            throw new Exception(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

**NO WEB SERVICE**

```
[WebMethod(Description = "Grava uma agencia no banco de dados.")]
    public bool GravarAgencia(string jsonAgencia)
    {
        try
        {
            Agencia ag = new Agencia();

            ag = DeserializarAgencia(jsonAgencia);
            //negocioAgencia.GravarAgencia(ag.NomeAg.ToUpper(), ag.FotoUsuario, ag.NomeDeUsuario, ag.Email, ag.Telefone, ag.Senha);
            //return true;


            if (negocioAgencia.ValidarTudo(ag.NomeAg, ag.NomeAg, ag.Telefone, ag.Email).Equals(true))
            {
                negocioAgencia.GravarAgencia(ag.NomeAg.ToUpper(), ag.FotoUsuario, ag.NomeDeUsuario, ag.Email, ag.Telefone, ag.Senha);
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Só pra lembrar que no navegador o processo de persistência acontece normalmente, sem exceções.

Comment: O erro é no webservice, faça um log com o erro e você vai ver o que tá errado.

Comment: Eu acabei de gravar os dados usando a versão do navegador e não ocorreu qualquer erro. Os dados foram persistidos normalmente. A exceção está ocorrendo apenas no aplicativo.

Comment: E isso quer dizer alguma coisa? O erro diz: "**O servidor não pôde processar a solicitação**". Está claro que o erro é no _web service_. Aliás, fica bem difícil tentar te ajudar sem ver nenhum código.

Comment: Esse `throw new Exception(e.Message);` é péssimo porque você acaba perdendo a informação de origem da exception.